# Button Event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am creating a webpage in c# .Net 4.5.

I have a button on the page and has a OnClick event. But when I run the webpage and click on the button the click event is not working.

```
<div id="sb-site">
    <div class="container" style="padding-right:10px;width:100%">                      
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
     Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />              
    </div>
</div>
```

Button Click Event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b;
    b = a;
}
```

after doing more debugging , found that I have a Sliderbar JQuery that I have got it from this site http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/, When I disable this query the button works.

Comment: Please post your code for button click event

Comment: Why upvote for this??

Comment: change the causes validation property of that particular button

Comment: If this is the code then what you want to do with the button click?

Comment: Even this code is not working Ullas.

Comment: Here just assigning the value of 'a' to 'b'. Then what you want to do?

Comment: Even If I add more buttons and create a OnClick event not working.

Comment: Actually what you want to do with the button click?

Comment: Ullas, I don't think you understood my question. I need to make the OnClick event working to add more code this button.

Comment: make sure that you have put `<asp:Buttonbutton>` tag in `<form>` tag.

Comment: How do you know this isn't working?

Comment: I Don't now why I have down vote without an answer.

Comment: Ricky, I have the button inside the form tag.

Comment: Enigmativity, I put a break point , also I try writing something into textbox on this click event.

Comment: You actually have two down votes and one up vote. Also, you should always include a @TTK (addressed to the person you're replying to) in your replies to comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Adam the author of Slidebars.

Slidebars has previously had issues with .net applications. It's due to the plugin attempting to move the containers. This has been removed in the upcoming version (0.10), which is due to be released this week. You can keep an eye out on the plugins page or on GitHub for the update.

If you can't wait, and want to continue development straight away, open up slidebars.js (version 0.9.4), and comment-out/remove the following lines 72, 79, and 87.

```
if (!$site.parent().is('body')) $site.appendTo('body');
if (!$left.parent().is('body')) $left.appendTo('body');
if (!$right.parent().is('body')) $right.appendTo('body');
```

This seems to solve the issues other users have also experienced with .net.

Please let me know if that helps.

Thanks, Adam

Comment: Just to let you know version .10 was released today, and fixes this issue. Thanks, Adam.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your button in content place holder.
Please look in below code for the same.

```
<div id="sb-site">
    <div class="container" style="padding-right:10px;width:100%">                      
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">        
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
               Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />              
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I tried the button on the child page well as the Master page. The Code snippet that I have it in my question is in the master page, but none of the event fires.